# SSRS 2008 - PDF - Dynamic footer size or text box towards the end of the page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, pdf-generation

I am using Reporting Services 2008 and developing a Report which has Page Header and a Page Footer. Currently in my Page Header and Footer I am using multiple items together for example, my footer has to be designed as follows.

Textbox1 ( disclaimer 1)

Textbox2 ( disclaimer 2)

The condition I am using is to show the Textbox2 only on page 1 and show both the textboxes on the page 2 (the final page). When I included both the text boxes as part of the footer and hide the Textbox1 on page1 and show only on page 2 the, I see that although the Textbox1 is Hidden, still see the Space occupied by the textbox1. 
I learnt that the size of the header/footer is fixed and can not be changed or does not automatically grow or shrink based on the content.
As a workaround tried having fixed report size ( W 8.5in, H 10.5in ) and Body size ( 8in, 8.5in) and had the Textbox2 as part of the footer and brought Textbox1 outside the footer (just on top of the footer). The Textbox1 on page 2 is not sticking towards the end of the page. It is getting printed towards the content of the page. What exactly to do inorder to have the textbox1 content printed towards the end. 
Please note that I need to have this exported as PDF and not as a report viewer. I have noticed that the output alignments for print layout (export) vs. report viewer are different.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The footer space occupied by the textbox1 (although its hidden on page 2 ) can not shrink. 
The Textbox1 on page 2 is not sticking towards the end of the page - can not fix.

Looks like both the problems can not be addressed by SSRS. So decided to move to Crystal reports and it has Report header/footer and page header/footer which solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you set TextBox1 and textBox2 to the smallest possible height and set the autogrow properties of both textboxes to Auto, then shrink your footer to the smallest possible size this should solve your space problem. as the header / footer will expand and contract with the size of the textboxes

when you say "*The Textbox1 on page 2 is not sticking towards the end of the page*".
i am assuming you mean one of the textboxes is moving when textbox1 is made visible,

if that is the case, instead of setting the visibility property of textbox one, try set the Font Color property to match your background color effectively making the box invisible.

I hope that all makes sense.

Comment: I do no think so. Page footer of the crystal report is fixed and the size cannot change dynamically like the 'detail' section, even if you have placed a 'can grow' controls in it.